# cheapest flights within k stops, how to add caching mechanic?

Tags: algorithm

https://aaronice.gitbook.io/lintcode/graph_search/cheapest-flights-within-k-stops
https://leetcode.com/problems/cheapest-flights-within-k-stops/

So a typical leetcode question

```
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @param {number[][]} flights
 * @param {number} src
 * @param {number} dst
 * @param {number} k
 * @return {number}
 */

var findCheapestPrice = function (n, arr, start, end, k) {
  // * l: node -> node; cycle
  const graph = {};
  // * l: each slot contains the shortest path so far
  const dist = new Array(n).fill(Infinity);
  // * l: stand there 0; never reach inf
  dist[start] = 0;

  // * l: preprocess: b(g)
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    const s = arr[i][0];
    const e = arr[i][1];
    const d = arr[i][2];

    // * l: 1 direction
    // * l: school bag theory
    if (graph[s] === undefined) {
      graph[s] = [];
    }

    graph[s].push([e, d]);
  } // end loop

  const g_seen = new Set();
  let min = Infinity;

  const dfs = (curr_node, curr_k, acc) => {
    // * curr
    dist[curr_node] = Math.min(dist[curr_node], acc);

    const edges = graph[curr_node];
    if (edges) {
      // * l: lock
      g_seen.add(curr_node);

      // * l: loop
      for (let i = 0; i < edges.length; ++i) {
        // * l: ind vs edge_ind
        const next_ind = edges[i][0];
        const next_por_d = edges[i][1];

        // * if next pt is end, no need k; the k will block you (l: steal)
        if (next_ind === end) {
          min = Math.min(min, acc + next_por_d);
          // * l: each slot contains the shortest path so far
          dist[next_ind] = Math.min(dist[next_ind], acc + next_por_d);
          continue;
        }

        // * l: what is curr
        // * l: what is next
        // * l: mix up will be bad idea
        // * hit cycle, next (l: steal)
        if (g_seen.has(next_ind)) continue;

        // * cannot go to next level, next (l: steal)
        if (curr_k + 1 > k) {
          continue;
        }

        // * l: g_seen ~= [e1, e2, e3]_path
        // * l: g_seen -> cycle -> stop
        // * l: dfs return -> g_seen etc revert
        // * l: dfs come back from bottom -> portion res -> use in this level
        dfs(next_ind, curr_k + 1, acc + next_por_d);
      } // end loop

      // * l: unlock
      g_seen.delete(curr_node);
    } // end if edge
  };

  // * l: process
  dfs(start, 0, 0);

  const res = dist[end];
  if (res === Infinity) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return res;
  }
};
```

Get a Time limit exceed on this test case

n = 94

src =
17

dst =
33

k =
39

flights:

https://pastebin.pl/view/98c1ed99

**My question:**

1. How do I add a caching mechanic based on the current code structure?
2. It is using acc to accumulated the distance so far.
3. this is an accepted answer by other people, The dfs return partial min result, which is a good idea.

```
const findCheapestPrice = (n, flights, src, dst, k) => {
  const graph = {};
  const memo = {};

  for (const [x, y, price] of flights) {
    if (!graph[x]) graph[x] = [];
    graph[x].push([y, price]);
  }

  const traverse = (x, stops) => {
    const key = `${x}-${stops}`;
    let min = Infinity; // min price

    // destination reached: add cost from destination to src
    if (x === dst) return 0;
    if (stops === 0) return -1;
    if (!graph[x]) return -1;
    if (memo[key]) return memo[key];

    for (const [y, price] of graph[x]) {
      const total = traverse(y, stops - 1);

      if (total === -1) continue; // invalid route: continue
      min = Math.min(min, total + price); // valid route: update min cost
    }

    // memoize node-stops: min price
    // price can change for each node based on number of stops
    memo[key] = min;
    return min !== Infinity ? min : -1;
  };

  const output = traverse(src, k + 1);
  return output !== Infinity ? output : -1;
};
```